# Verify the identity: $2\cos^4 x - \cos^2 x - 2 \sin^2 x\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = \cos^2 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Verify the identity: $$2\cos^4 x - \cos^2 x - 2 \sin^2 x\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = \cos^2 2x$$

There are so many routes to start on this.  I have tried a bunch, have gotten stumped at each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2\cos^4 x - \cos^2 x - 2 \sin^2 x\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$$

$$=\cos^2 x(2\cos^2 x-1)-\sin^2 x(2\cos^2 x-1)$$

$$=(2\cos^2 x-1)(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)$$

Now apply [Double-Angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) Formulas